# Failed to create topics","exception":"\norg.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

```
{
   "mdc":{
      
   },
   "timestamp":"2021-05-11 11:48:04.055",
   "level":"ERROR",
   "logger":"org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner",
   "message":"Failed to create topics",
   "exception":"\"\norg.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: Creating topics with default partitions/replication factor are only supported in CreateTopicRequest version 4+. The following topics need values for partitions and replicas:"
```

Please suggest what changes are required as i am getting this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you are new here. You should always include version information and full stack trace for questions like this.

Upgrade your broker to >= 2.4 or set the binder replication factor property.

See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/4161f875ede0446ab1d485730c51e6a2c5baa37a

> - Change default replication factor to -1

> Binder now uses a default value of -1 for replication factor signaling the
> broker to use defaults. Users who are on Kafka brokers older than 2.4,
> need to set this to the previous default value of 1 used in the binder.

> In either case, if there is an admin policy that requires replication factor > 1,
> then that value must be used instead.

Comment: Using Kafka Version <kafka.version>2.6.0</kafka.version> but still getting this issue

Comment: That's the client version; the broker needs to be 2.4 or later; set the binder property to the replication factor you want.

Comment: Thanks Gary, added binder property to the replication factor "1" it works...
But previously we are using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.version "3.0.7" at that time issue didn't occurs , currently we are using "3.1.2" and issue occurs. 
Is it because of replication factor changes from "1" to "-1” ?
So, we need to explicitly add the replication factor property.

Comment: Yes, it was a new feature added to Kafka Brokers at 2.4; users complained that SCSt overrode that behavior and forced them to configure it in both places. In order to satisfy those users, SCSt 3.1 changed its default to -1 so the broker configuration would win. As the documentation stated, this meant that users with old brokers would have to change it to the old default.  Price of progress.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the default replication factor(-1) with a non negative value fixed the issue for me.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.replication-factor=1
```

For `application.yaml` file use:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.replicationFactor: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to following . The fluent api allows to give partitions and replicas.

```
@Bean
    NewTopic topicBytes() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("reflectoring-bytes").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. And the following link helped me to solve it.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/1134

The property path for cloud kafka stream is different.
Instead of     **spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder**
we have to use **spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder**